# how to disable skipper in sailsjs v10.x

Tags: sails.js

I want to get like express req.files, because the sails new version has already include it automatically, i'm not familiar with it and the doc about it is relatively poor, so how to disable skipper in sails' new version? thx

Answer (score 1):

The [docs for Skipper](https://github.com/balderdashy/skipper) have gotten a lot better, but if you really want to go back to the old Express bodyParser and its [known issues](http://andrewkelley.me/post/do-not-use-bodyparser-with-express-js.html), you can do so by setting the `bodyParser` property in **config/http.js**:

```
bodyParser: require('express').bodyParser()
```

You'll need to `npm install express@^3.0` in your project for this to work.